# How to create a vector with factor level frequency?

Tags: r

I have a factor F. I need to create a vector V of the same length of F in which there are values of the frequencies of factor levels. 
For example:

```
F <- factor(c("a","b","c","b","a","a","a","b"))

table(F)
F
a b c 
4 3 1
```

V should be:

```
V
[1] 4 3 1 3 4 4 4 3
```

Comment: Don't use `F` as a variable name, though.  It is used by R as an alternative to `FALSE` and you risk causing yourself to have nasty surprises if you try to use it for any other purpose!

Comment: I'm sorry, you're right

Answer (score 5):

We can use `ave`

```
ave(seq_along(X), X, FUN = length)
#[1] 4 3 1 3 4 4 4 3
```

Or use the `table` itself

```
as.vector(table(X)[X])
#[1] 4 3 1 3 4 4 4 3
```

Answer (score 4):

```
x <- c("a","b","c","b","a","a","a","b")
```

Then, depending on whether you want the output to be named,

```
table(x)[x]
# x
# a b c b a a a b 
# 4 3 1 3 4 4 4 3 
c(table(x)[x])
# a b c b a a a b 
# 4 3 1 3 4 4 4 3 
as.numeric(table(x)[x])
# [1] 4 3 1 3 4 4 4 3
unname(table(x)[x])
# [1] 4 3 1 3 4 4 4 3
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
t=table(F)
as.numeric(sapply(1:length(F), function(i) t[F[i]]))
```

**output**

```
[1] 4 3 1 3 4 4 4 3
```